# Is it correct to use 首都 for capital of province?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, mandarin, usage, simplified-characters

I am trying to do a cultural project on the city of Harbin. However, I'm not sure if it is correct to say this. I found out that Harbin was the capital of the province of Heilongjiang. If I said, 哈尔滨是黑龙江的首都, would it make sense since 首都 means capital.

Comment: 北京是中国的**首都**: Beijing is the **capital** of China.
拉萨是西藏的**首府**: Lhasa is the **capital** of Tibet.
西安是陕西的**首府/省会**: Xi'an is the **capital** of Shaanxi.
我今天要去**省城**: I need to go to the provincial capital (city) today.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, you should use `省会` (provincial capital) instead, i.e. `哈尔滨是黑龙江的省会`. You could also use `省城` (in a little old-style), or `首府` (especially for `自治区`(autonomous region)).

`首都` is only used for the capital of a country, e.g.`北京是中国的首都`.

Comment: Also, 省城 - http://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%9C%81%E5%9F%8E *省城，是汉语词汇，解释为省政府驻地，省会，首府。*

Comment: 自治縣的行政駐地通常被稱為「首府」，如呼和浩特、烏魯木齊、銀川、南寧、拉薩。

Comment: actually, 首府 is not so widely used in daily languages

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid it is not very suitable,   首都 is capital，Beijing is the capital of china, the capital of province is 省会，guangzhou is the 省会 of guangdong province.